# Why I get different layouts in iPhone5's and iPhone6's simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to make a ViewController in Xcode using the storyboard, but when I run the simulator I get different results...

In iPhone5 simulator:

[image: iPhone5 Simulator]

In iPhone6 simulator:

[image: iPhone6 simulator]

Comment: Please describe the constraints you are using for the top bar in particular

Comment: looks like you have created your view on a 4-inch simulated view controller, and didn't give any auto layout or autoresizing for the elements, assign those first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your autolayout constraints.

Likely the star and wand have their x-values set relative to the left side of the screen. Set their x-values relative to the right side.

The gray box height should be a set pixel height (`44px` is default). You could have it relative to the height of the `self.view` but setting it to `44px` is definitely the standard way.

I could help more if you took screenshots of your autolayout constraints and storyboard.

**Edit:** As Arpit Dhamane pointed out, `44px` is not default, `44pt` is. [Useful guide on iOS Layouts](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html). I'm not sure how `autolayout` handles things but I'm fairly certain it is in `pt` not `px` so `44pt` is the correct size for your navigation bar.

Also, I would use `UIButtons` for the wand and star. The image would be sized with `setImage(...)` then `button.imageEdgeInset = UIEdgeInsets(...)` with a `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right` to 1/4 the height of the navbar so the image is 1/2 the navbar height. I don't know if this is convention but it works well with appearance and accessibility.

**PS:** I don't use `storyboards` and do everything programmatically so I'm not sure how useful the `UIButton` part is for you.

Comment: the 44 is not the standard size for the navigation bar for all ios devices, it is only for the ipad, for iphone it is 88px and ipad retina also it is 88px. The 44px you are recommending is the suggested height of the icons of the items we add on the navigation bar. Refer this link, http://click-labs.com/ios-8-design-cheat-sheet-and-free-iphone6plus-gui-psd/

Comment: This depends on whether the display is @2x or not. I should have said 44pt is the default (because it is http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html). You're right that 44px is not default because 1px is not the same size for different devices. Im not sure how `autolayout` handles pt vs px. (I always hard code my apps). Thanks for correction.